# Is it possible to run embeded Tomcat 9 using another maven plugin instead of using cargo?

Tags: maven-plugin, tomcat9

With the ***tomcat7-maven-plugin***, i can run an embeded tomcat just by running the following command: ***mvn tomcat7:run -pl webapp***

I wish to do the same with an embeded tomcat 9 server, without using cargo. Is it possible? Does someone already deal with it?

Thanks.